# Compilation error after integrating JQuery in Angular 2 app

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

I have an Angular 2 project administered with npm and I recently ran

```
typings install dt~jquery --save --global
```

to add the JQuery type definition to my project.

npm then downloaded this type definition file to the directory node_modules as expected.

The problem is now that the Typescript compiler (using `npm run tsc:w`) complains:

```
$ npm run tsc:w
```

> node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3246,5): error TS2300: Duplicate
>   identifier 'export='. typings/globals/jquery/index.d.ts(601,5): error
>   TS2374: Duplicate string index signature.
>   typings/globals/jquery/index.d.ts(2850,5): error TS2374: Duplicate
>   string index signature. typings/globals/jquery/index.d.ts(2851,5):
>   error TS2375: Duplicate number index signature.
>   typings/globals/jquery/index.d.ts(3224,5): error TS2300: Duplicate
>   identifier 'export='. 18:48:59 - Compilation complete. Watching for
>   file changes.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transpiler gives duplicate definition error because you seem to have installed the definition files into multiple locations in your project:

```
node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts
typings/globals/jquery/index.d.ts
```

Try to uninstall `@types/jquery` module by typing this line:

```
npm remove @types/jquery --save-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I was following a udemy class on typescript.

He explained `typings` then `@types`, but really quick at the beginning of the @types video he says to

### Delete 2 things:

- the `typings` folder
- `typings.json`

I totally missed him saying that the first time.

Also, my SystemJS was missing the map part (I didn't think it was necessary, but I guess it is.)

```
SystemJS.config({
    map: {
        "jQuery": "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
    },
    baseURL: '/',
    packages: {
        '/': {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
});
```

Once I had all that in place, everything worked.